# How do I modify environment variables between tests at runtime with pytest?

Tags: environment-variables, pytest

I have a use case where I have several functions which depend on the environment (dev/staging/prod). I pre load these into a variable (in this case `ENV`) and is used across my util functions.

Following is an MWE.

`.env`

```
MYENV=staging
```

`config.py`

```py
import os
import dotenv

dotenv.load_dotenv()

ENV = os.environ.get("MYENV")
```

`util.py`

```py
from config import ENV

def resolve_db(db: str) -> str:
    return f"{ENV}_" + db
```

`conftest.py`

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def dev_env(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("MYENV", "dev")


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def staging_env(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("MYENV", "staging")


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def prod_env(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("MYENV", "prod")
```

`test_util.py`

```py
from util import resolve_db
import os

def test_resolve_db_dev(dev_env):
    assert resolve_db("stackoverflow") == "dev_stackoverflow"
    
def test_resolve_db_staging(staging_env):
    assert resolve_db("stackoverflow") == "staging_stackoverflow"

def test_resolve_db_prod(prod_env):
    assert resolve_db("stackoverflow") == "prod_stackoverflow"
```

```sh
$ pytest
===================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /mnt/c/Users/name/PROJECTS/test-pytest-env
plugins: anyio-3.5.0, cov-3.0.0, deadfixtures-2.2.1, html-3.1.1, metadata-1.11.0, timeout-2.1.0
collected 3 items

test_util.py F.F                                                                                                                                        [100%]

========================================================================== FAILURES ===========================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________ test_resolve_db_dev _____________________________________________________________________

dev_env = None

    def test_resolve_db_dev(dev_env):
>       assert resolve_db("stackoverflow") == "dev_stackoverflow"
E       AssertionError: assert 'staging_stackoverflow' == 'dev_stackoverflow'
E         - dev_stackoverflow
E         + staging_stackoverflow

test_util.py:5: AssertionError
____________________________________________________________________ test_resolve_db_prod _____________________________________________________________________

prod_env = None

    def test_resolve_db_prod(prod_env):
>       assert resolve_db("stackoverflow") == "prod_stackoverflow"
E       AssertionError: assert 'staging_stackoverflow' == 'prod_stackoverflow'
E         - prod_stackoverflow
E         + staging_stackoverflow

test_util.py:11: AssertionError
=================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================
FAILED test_util.py::test_resolve_db_dev - AssertionError: assert 'staging_stackoverflow' == 'dev_stackoverflow'
FAILED test_util.py::test_resolve_db_prod - AssertionError: assert 'staging_stackoverflow' == 'prod_stackoverflow'
================================================================= 2 failed, 1 passed in 0.08s =================================================================
```

I don't understand how I can monkeypatch the ENV variable at runtime to help with my tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load variables from .env file for pytests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763151/how-to-load-variables-from-env-file-for-pytests)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen not exactly. My app is configured to load from `.env`. I would like to override the environment variables read into a variable during my tests. So I either monkeypatch `ENV` or I monkeypatch the environment variable. What would be the right approach here?

Comment: Try patching ENV?

Comment: Monkeypatching ENV is indeed the correct way, e.g. `monkeypatch.setattr(util, "ENV", "dev")`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, where I wanted to provide a test env only for certain test functions but not for others. In addition, there is a larger number of env vars. Therefore I did not put this detail into the fixture but stored it in separate .env file(s).

What I came up with is a combination of `python_dotenv` and `pytest`'s `monkeypatch` in a function-scoped fixture.

The key is to not manipulate the env permanently by using `dotenv.load_dotenv()`. Instead I only read the values with `dotenv.dotenv_values()` and forward them to `monkeypatch`.

```
import os
import pytest
import pytest_check as check
import dotenv
from pathlib import Path

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def tempEnv(monkeypatch):
    filePath = Path(__file__).parent / '<test_specific>.env'
    check.is_true(filePath.exists())
    entries = dotenv.dotenv_values(dotenv_path=filePath)
    check.is_not_none(entries)
    for k, v in entries.items():
        monkeypatch.setenv(name=k, value=v)


def test_patched_env(tempEnv):
    check.is_in('<some_var>', os.environ)
    ...

def test_orig_env():
    check.is_not_in('<some_var>', os.environ)
    ...
```